# What are each of the separate mongodb-org packages for ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am installing mongodb on a local ubuntu vm and I'm using the official Mongo supported packages per the official instructions. However, I don't know what each of these packages contain. I know this is a merely informational question, but I've googled and not found the answer.

mongodb-org
mongodb-org-server
mongodb-org-shell
mongodb-org-mongos
mongodb-org-tools

What do each of these packages provide? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the details of each item from [MongoDB official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#mongodb-packages).

[image]